# Why am I getting an exception when running a JAR file from the command prompt?

Tags: java, exception, jar, command-prompt

Hi I have made a runnable JAR file useing export option on eclipse. However, when I go to run the file via command prompt i get the following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.RsrcURLConnection.getInputStream(RsrcURLConnection.java:43)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
```

Does any one have any ideas as to what im doing wrong? pretty new to the whole creating runnable files etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your jar is compiled with a newer version of java than the computer you are running it on.

Comment: how do i get the current version

Comment: To check the version on the pc you are running it on. Type java -version in the cmd prompt. To update it to the newest version go here : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: You developed it with an newer version than java 3, update to the version you compiled it with.

Comment: that is the version on the machine

Comment: I understand, but when you developed it, you did it with a different version. Do you use eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the jar file look for the file META-INF/MANIFEST-MF. This file should have an entry

```
Main-Class : <you fully qualified classname having main method>
```

Check if the class  you mentioned as Main-Class has a  main method (`public static void main(String[] arg)`)