# Java program not functioning properly only when running the exported jar

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I have a Java program (using JavaSE-1.6).

When i execute the program in eclipse there is no problem and i get the following:

[image: How it should be]

But when i export it to an executable jar and run it i get the following:

[image: How it is]

Has anyone ever experienced anything like this?

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.RsrcURLConnection.getInputStr
eam(RsrcURLConnection.java:43)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.getResource(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:56)
```

Comment: Does it execute the correct main-method of the correct class?

Comment: try to run using java -jar and post us the stacktrace (if any) :)
Probably something about eclipse not exporting the resources or not being able to run with the selected look and feel.

Comment: probably your classpath is missing for external libaries

Comment: Probably you are using other jars in your program(in eclipse) and those jars are now unavailable after you packaged your project.

Comment: @Adarsh im not using any other jars in my program it is a very simple and short program

Comment: Take at look at this, I suppose is the same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452735/why-am-i-getting-an-exception-when-running-a-jar-file-from-the-command-prompt

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to carefully read this page, it's just a very basic information about jar file:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html

There is nothing special about jar file, in fact it is just an archive, like *.zip or *.rar. What `java` bin does is actually just to process the jar file based on the metadata inside and then run the classes inside.

A few things that you can do to debug:

1. look into jar files, and check if all referenced files are complete: images, properties files, etc. And then check that the path is correctly referenced. Most of the times it's just a matter of interchange between slash and backslash.
2. Check jar files mainfest in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF: if your program is using external libraries, you need to specify them in this file with the correct path!
3. If your program does not have a logging system (e.g. log4j) then most probably the error log is printed on System.out stream (which is null/nowhere if you run the jar by double click-ing the executable jar. Hence, to look at system.out, you should try running your jar file from the shell command line: 
   `java -jar yourjarfile.jar`

Comment: ive added a stack trace from java -jar in my question could you have a look?

Comment: It looks like a java mismatch version between Eclipse and the java you are using when running it from shell. What happened is that the java you are using in shell not yet have the method that was being called at: (RsrcURLConnection.java:43)

Comment: so how do i fix this?

Comment: You should check whcih java version your Eclipse is using when compiling the classes. You can check this it Eclipse properties -> java runtime. And then you should run your jar file with the same (or newer version) by setting the PATH to point to the newer version of java.

Comment: ive set it to Java 6 (it had (perfect match)) when selecting but i still get the error

Comment: I checked RsrcURLConnection.java line 43, apparently here it was trying to call URLDecoder.[decode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) which is probably not there in the JVM you are using to run the jar file.

Comment: As suggested by Aaron Digulla, it is possible that your application is calling the referenced class from the wrong JAR files.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this behavior is that you have two different versions of the same JAR on the classpath.

Depending on how you start your application, one or the other takes precedence and shadows the other.

If you use Maven, then the [maven-duplicate-finder-plugin](https://github.com/ning/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin) is for you.